# Different item sizes Collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collection view, and I load some items and each item has different size images, I am trying to make each item the size of the current image. I am having some troubles setting the size of the item depending of the size of the image, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Implement UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate in your controller and then you can return size for each element in the delegate method, – collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:

See this link for more available options;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html